# Drools KieScanner auto-update notification

Tags: drools, kie

In my current system, I have a Nexus maven repository which holds the compiled rules (kjar) for Drools. When I start the system, it gets the LATEST version of rules from nexus. I then create a KieScanner and start it, with a scan frequency of 10 seconds.

I cannot figure out if there is a way to be notified when the rules are updated. So after the scanner detects a new version and downloads it, I would like to know about it.

Is there a way to know when the rules get updated when using a KieScanner?

Comment: Drools or KieScanner dont provide any such kind of notification. You may configure alter system on nexus repository when there is change in any artifact.

Answer (score 0):

We recently implemented a listener interface for the KieScanner, which should address your use-case as well.

Ref [DROOLS-1565](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1565)